# How can I asynchro two jquery that are running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vzsUd/70/) on JS Fiddle.
As you see in the demo, two animations are moving synchronously.
What if I want to start bottom animation 0.5 sec after top animation started moving?

How can I modify my code?

Here's a document for [textillate plugin](https://github.com/jschr/textillate)

```
<h1 class="tlt">
    <ul class="texts">
        <li data-in-effect="fadeInDown" data-out-effect="fadeOutDown" data-in-delay="10">Some Title</li>   
        <li data-in-effect="fadeInDown" data-out-effect="fadeOutDown" data-in-delay="10">Another Title</li>
        <li data-in-effect="fadeInDown" data-out-effect="fadeOutDown" data-in-delay="10">Last Title</li>
    </ul>
</h1>


<h1 class="tlt">
    <ul class="texts">
        <li data-in-effect="fadeInDown" data-out-effect="fadeOutDown" data-in-delay="10">Some Title</li>   
        <li data-in-effect="fadeInDown" data-out-effect="fadeOutDown" data-in-delay="10">Another Title</li>
        <li data-in-effect="fadeInDown" data-out-effect="fadeOutDown" data-in-delay="10">Last Title</li>
    </ul>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made your second `tlt` into `tlt2` and just called textillate on that, except with a `initialDelay` parameter.

```
<h1 class="tlt2">
    ....

// JavaScript
$('.tlt2').textillate({
    initialDelay: 500,
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I have appended a piece of code with different settings for second animation. In particular I have added a 'delay' parameter.

```
$('.tlt2').textillate({
   in: {
       shuffle: false,
       sync: true,
       delay: 1
   },
   out: {
         effect: 'fadeOutRightBig',
         shuffle: false,
         sync: true
   },
   loop: true
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/kte5401m/